# Loading sf::Image by QDialog

Tags: c++, qt, sfml

Is there a easy way to load sf::Image using for example QDialog or other library? I mean I want to load image for using it in sfml by "Choose image..." window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [QFileDialog](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#) to get the path of the given image:

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"),
                                            QDir::currentDirPath() ,
                                            tr("Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)"));
if (!fileName.isEmpty()) {
    // Now you can init your sf::image

}
```

According to the official documentation of [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Image.php), you can use the [loadFromFile](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Image.php#a9e4f2aa8e36d0cabde5ed5a4ef80290b) function

```
sf::Image image;
if (image.loadFromFile(filename.toStdString())) {
   std::cout << "image loaded with success";
}
```